# Lubuntu freezes during login attempts

Tags: boot, lubuntu, login, ssd, freeze

I’m unable to login to my user account my laptop only has one user and when I try applying the correct password on start up it freezes, the mouse still moves, the clock in the corner of the screen is frozen as well and when I leave the computer alone it will go into hibernation mode.
ran a live instance and checked my SSD with gparted everything says the hard drive is fine but when I reboot to try again it’s the same result.

• Hardware

Late MacBook Pro 2008.

• Operation system

Lubuntu 22.04

The last thing I did was install an update in terminal “sudo apt update” I ran out of space on my SSD while applying the update, noticed this went to clear it and when I checked to see if everything was cleared my SSD showed that I still had zero space left… it was then I decided to restart to see if everything was fine and I’ve been locked out of my laptop because of the freezing ever since.

I have a flash drive with lubuntu installed on it if anyone knows how to fix this in a live instance terminal please let me know.

Comment: I’m wondering if I should attempt to remove the login but I’m unsure if this will cause damage to my OS I’ve tried ctrl+alt+f5 but nothing happens getting kind of desperate.

Comment: FYI: This was also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/login-screen-freezes-when-correct-password-is-applied/4271  (*but was marked as solved possibly in error by OP*)

Comment: If you've run out of space (esp. in $HOME or the user directory; which maybe on a different partition or same partition as /; we can't know unless told) the system can appear to *freeze* but just be ultra slow as if frozen..  Logging in via text terminal should work, OR you can create space using a *live* system then deleting files from there or just checking for issues.  `gparted` isn't included on Lubuntu *live* systems but you didn't specify what checks you performed however most only check *metadata* on file-system level & not for any data/block problems..

Comment: Hey again guiverc it’s nice to see you again didn’t realize you posted here as well sorry for the confusion I tried to message you on the lubuntu forums but the system wouldn’t allow my messages to go through, possibly because I’m a new user? 

Anyway I’m going to try to clear some  space in both $home and user directory this time I’ll contact you again soon.

Comment: I’ll also post photos and some more info when I get back.